# Javascript YouTube API v3 upload - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, video, upload, youtube

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube using javascript. I found the following sample:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/yt-upload-javascript/

https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html

The sample works the majority of the time, but I notice that for videos larger than ~2GB, the upload does not start. In the console, I get the following message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet&upload_id=.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

This does not happen for files smaller than 2GB. This happens on both my page and the sample. I understood that YouTube removed its restriction on files larger than 2GB. I am logged in with my YouTube account on the page. The account has a channel already and is verified to allow long videos.

Any idea what is happening here? Why only for large files?

**EDIT - Request from Chrome network tool:**

> Request URL:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet&upload_id=SOME_ID
>
> Request Headers
>   - Provisional headers are shown
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Content-Range: bytes 0-2255876615/2255876616
>
> Content-Type: video/mp4
>
> Origin: https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com
>
> Referer:
>   https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.103 Safari/537.36
>
> Query String Parameters
>
> uploadType: resumable
>
> part: snippet
>
> upload_id: SOME_ID

Comment: Please provide all other data about HTTP response (status code, body content, headers, etc...), I have a clue about what is the problem, but I need that data to confirm

Comment: I added the headers shown in the Chrome network tool @dseminara.